# How to get Wireguard VPN to connect over Tor?

Tags: networking, routing, vpn, wireguard, tor

The following Mullvad documentation describes how to get an OpenVPN VPN to connect over Tor:

https://mullvad.net/es/help/tor-and-mullvad-vpn/

I would like to achieve the same result but using Wireguard instead of OpenVPN. What edits do I need to make to my Wireguard .conf file to achieve this result?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this. TOR is already anonymising you. Using a VPN creates an unnecessary third party which you need to trust. Trust = Bad.

Comment: @Panki Its not to improve security of Tor but improve security of VPN by ensuring VPN operator does not know my true IP. Tor alone is not sufficient for many sites as Tor exit IPs are treated as hostile.

Answer (score 0):

From the Tor project official website support pages:

> [What about distributed denial of service attacks?](https://support.torproject.org/#abuse_ddos)
>
> [...]
>
> But because **Tor only transports correctly formed TCP streams**, not
> all IP packets, **you cannot send UDP packets over Tor**. (You can't
> do specialized forms of this attack like SYN flooding either.)
>
> [...]

So at least Tor's FAQ documents UDP cannot be used through Tor.

From WireGuard's official site:

> [Known Limitations](https://www.wireguard.com/known-limitations/)
>
> [...]
>
> [TCP Mode](https://www.wireguard.com/known-limitations/#tcp-mode)
>
> **WireGuard explicitly does not support tunneling over TCP**, due to the
> classically terrible network performance of tunneling TCP-over-TCP.
> Rather, transforming WireGuard's UDP packets into TCP is the job of an
> upper layer of obfuscation (see previous point), and can be
> accomplished by projects like [udptunnel](https://github.com/rfc1036/udptunnel) and [udp2raw](https://github.com/wangyu-/udp2raw-tunnel).

WireGuard documents it won't use TCP.

So to have WireGuard work across Tor, it requires to be first encapsulated into yet-an-other (TCP) tunnel. That means both sides: the anonymous client and the non-trusted remote VPN provider must implement such TCP encapsulation first, since OP doesn't control *both* sides.

The chances to find a VPN provider providing WireGuard-over-udptunnel or WireGuard-over-udp2raw (though the nature of *udp2raw* is probably incompatible with Tor) or even the equivalent of WireGuard-over-socat as service rather than *only* WireGuard  are pretty low: you won't be able to use WireGuard over Tor.

Comment: Should you find such provider and as importantly this provider's documentation on how to handle the TCP encapsulation, you can come back and ask about it in case its documentation is not clear enough. It won't be WireGuard (-only) anymore though.